# C#: How to make a list from few string variables and put this to SOAP string

Tags: c#, soap

I have a problem with making a list from few variables.
i.e.:

```
var pos = "1; 2; 3"
var des = "aaa; bbb; ccc"
var pcs = "1.000; 44.000; 65.000"
```

I need to put this to something like list where I can use this data in soap string block.

data from these variables are an invoice lines like:

```
pos; des; pcs
1; aaa; 1.000
2; bbb; 44.000
3; ccc; 65.000
```

And finally I have to put this lines to blocks in SOAP message like this (one line is one RECEIVE_EINVOICE_LINE block which must be replicated with amount of lines):

```
<urn:LINES>
        <urn:RECEIVE_EINVOICE_LINE>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <urn:C00></urn:C00> <!-- pos-->
           <!--Optional:-->
           <urn:C14></urn:C14> <!-- des-->
           <!--Optional:-->
           <urn:D00></urn:D00> <!-- pcs-->
        </urn:RECEIVE_EINVOICE_LINE>
        <urn:RECEIVE_EINVOICE_LINE>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <urn:C00></urn:C00> <!-- pos-->
           <!--Optional:-->
           <urn:C14></urn:C14> <!-- des-->
           <!--Optional:-->
           <urn:D00></urn:D00> <!-- pcs-->
        </urn:RECEIVE_EINVOICE_LINE>
     </urn:LINES>
```

I'm really noob but I need to do this.

I have an idea to put this lines into lists but I don't know how to separate data from this variables and then merge this and put data into this soap message.

I tried to split this properly but I stucked with something like this:

```
class Program
{

    public void Pozycja(string pos)
    {
        var pos = "1; 2; 3";
        List<string> result = pos.Split(';').ToList();
    }

    public void Opis(string des)
    {
        var des = "aaa; bbb; ccc";
        List<string> result = des.Split(';').ToList();
    }

    public void Ilosc(string pcs)
    {
        var pcs = "1; 2; 3";
        List<string> result = pcs.Split(';').ToList();
    }

}
```

Sorry for my english, I tried my best! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that produces your desired xml:

```
var pos = "1; 2; 3";
var des = "aaa; bbb; ccc";
var pcs = "1.000; 44.000; 65.000";

var posList = pos.Split(';').ToList();
var desList = des.Split(';').ToList();
var pcsList = pcs.Split(';').ToList();

var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
{
    var ns = "http://www.example.com";
    var prefix = "urn";

    xw.WriteStartElement(prefix, "LINES", ns);

    for (int i = 0; i < posList.Count; i++)
    {
        xw.WriteStartElement(prefix, "RECEIVE_EINVOICE_LINE", ns);

        xw.WriteElementString(prefix, "C00", ns, posList[i]);
        xw.WriteElementString(prefix, "C14", ns, desList[i]);
        xw.WriteElementString(prefix, "D00", ns, pcsList[i]);

        xw.WriteEndElement();
    }

    xw.WriteEndElement();
}

var soapMessage = sb.ToString();
```